# How to extract data from columns using ODBC and FileMaker

Tags: c#, .net, database, odbc, filemaker

I'm using FileMaker ODBC in a .NET application.

I have an IDbReader (System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader) with some results. **FieldCount is 8** but when I invoke this

```
var isNull = reader.IsDBNull(0);
```

It throws an exception.

However, if I invoke this code:

```
var str = reader.GetString(0);
var isNull = reader.IsDBNull(0);
```

It works! So it seems that I cannot check if a value is null before retrieving the actual value. That doesn't make sense.

How is it supposed to work? I'm really out of ideas.

It seems that I have to extract fields blindly before checking for null! After I have called `reader.GetString()` on every field (every field is `string`), `reader.IsDBNull()` works perfecly.

The exception that is thrown is this:

> '((System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader)reader).IsDBNull(0)' threw an
>   exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException'
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       ErrorCode: -2146232009
>       Errors: {System.Data.Odbc.OdbcErrorCollection}
>       HResult: -2146232009
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: ""
>       Source: ""
>       StackTrace: "   en System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle,
>   RetCode retcode)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetColAttribute(Int32 iColumn,
>   SQL_DESC v3FieldId, SQL_COLUMN v2FieldId, HANDLER handler)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetSqlType(Int32 i)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)\r\n   en
>   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i)"
>       TargetSite: {Void HandleError(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcHandle, RetCode)}

This question is also related with this issue:
[IDbReader throwing exceptions for existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482532/idbreader-throwing-exceptions-for-existing-columns/36482799#36482799)